# an array to store atomic int

Tags: c++, arrays, multithreading, atomic

I had a requirement where an array of int suppose to be shared within 20 threads.
Threads can perform increment/decrements on array values.

Initially I used `mutex` lock/unlock on array for sync sharing. It worked but it's not execution safe. So planning to switch to `std::atomic`.

Is there a way using which I can create something like

```
std::array<std::atomic<int>, 10> array;
```

OR
any other way where "an array of int-atomic value " can be created ?

Comment: What is *execution safe*?

Comment: What happened when you tried to do what you suggest doing?

Comment: `std::array<std::atomic<int>, 10> array;` is valid.

Comment: tried below code on freebsd 10.0 version:#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
#include <array>


using namespace std ;



int main()
{
    std::array<std::atomic<int>, 3> ar ;
}
but getting below mentioned error: "/usr/include/c++/v1/atomic:539:2: error: <atomic> is not implemented"

Comment: @vijaysharma That means you need a newer/different compiler.  if *<atomic> is not implemented* then you will never be able to use a `std::atmic<int>`.

Comment: @Jarod42 please look into above reply from me.

Comment: @vijaysharma: Look at NathanOlivier's comment so.

Answer (score 1):

It got resolved with below code:

```
std::array<std::atomic<int>, 10> array={};
```

i was getting compiler issue but after setting flags and library for c++11 it got resolved.

Thanks for all of your comments.